# How can I create a read-only combobox in Pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a comboBox with items and I just want to display them without being able to select any of them.I searched in Qt Designer but I can't find the right property. Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it in the QtDesigner you have to connect the `currentIndexChanged` signal with a function that will revert the old value whatever the user selects:

Example:

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

```
class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        # Create a combo and set the second item to be selected
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(1)
        # Connect the combo currentIndexChanged signal
        self.combo.activated.connect(self.on_combo_change)
        # Setup layout
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def on_combo_change(self, index):
        # Whatever the user do, just ignore it and revert to
        # the old value.
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(1)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWidget()
mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is not what I am aiming for.My goal is the comboBox to be able to display its options but none of these options could be selected.Like a tebleWidget with the selectionMode set to NoSelection.

Comment: So you want the combobox to be enabled, user can click on, expand it, look for other values, but if he tries to change the value the old value will be set?

Comment: Exactly.I could change the selection background color to white to lose the blue color of the selected item, and connect if the index of the comboBox changes to setting the old value.But there is still the outline of the selection.

Comment: You cannot do that from the QtDesigner. But I changed my answer and created a simple example that does what you want.

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of the outline when something is selected in the comboBox?

Comment: Outline? Can you add a screenshoot to your question that shows what you mean? I'm running my code on a Mac and Linux, and I don't have any outlines.

Comment: It's like a dotted line around the text that is selected, it's more visible if you change the blue color of the selection background color to something else.

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what are you talking about :) Try poking a little bit with the [styleSheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html) for the QComboBox widget.

Comment: I added a screenshot if you can take a look.

Comment: I think you can change that with style sheets: [similar question](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3448).

Comment: This sounds terrible from a usability perspeective, what is the purpose of this non-changable ComboBox?

Comment: Have you looked into creating an AbstractItemModel with the items returning Qt::ItemIsSelectable => false? The steps would be to create the abstract item model and provide it to the combo box using the setModel() method.

Answer (score 2):

`QComboBox.setEditable(False)` should do it: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#setEditable